# How to remotely toggle offline mode in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

The question is quite simple: is it possible to toggle Thunderbird's *offline* mode from the command line?

The idea is to execute such command when certain connection/disconnection events happen (e.g. triggered by NetworkManager).